# Best route for open sourcing projects on GitHub/BitBucket, but not sharing sensitive files?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I want to open source some web projects I've done on GitHub, but there are some files that contain database passwords and the likes that I don't want to include obviously.

I could `git rm` those files, or add them to my `.gitignore`, but that would remove them from git and revision control all together, which I don't want to do.

How can I make it so when I push my changes to a repo, only certain files are included?

Comment: Note that if you previously added these files, you'll need to use [filter-branch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) to remove them from previous versions as well; else people will still be able to read them by going back in the history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually advise that people use the "template" pattern in this case.

For example, you have some `application.settings` file that contains things like database passwords, port bindings. etc.  Copy that file to `application.settings.template` and strip out all of the site-specific information, such as passwords and endpoints, leaving behind only the settings you want to be the default.

Then, add `application.settings` to your `.gitignore`.  Any time you introduce a new setting you will have to adjust both files, but this allows others to very easily see what has to be configured by looking for `*.template` files.  They would only need to copy those and remove the `.template` extension, then customize them as necessary.

This has some advantages:

1. The deployed settings won't be clobbered if someone is foolish enough to `git reset --hard` in production, as the actual settings file is not tracked by Git.
2. A developer won't be prevented from checking out a different branch because of local configuration changes (normally one would have to `git stash && git checkout other-branch && git stash pop` if the target branch has a different settings file than the current branch, and the developer has made local changes to the settings file).
3. As the actual settings file is ignored, it is very difficult to accidentally push it to a remote repository by accident.

A disadvantage is that new/modified settings in the template can't be merged in to a deployed setting file (but if you are in production you probably want to inspect the differences in the template file and apply those by hand anyway).  One will have to manually `git diff HEAD HEAD@{1} -- application.settings.template` after pulling or checking out a new branch to see what changed in the settings template.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a git submodule that is hosted privately, and included in your main git repo

Comment: This would work if (1) the private URL does not contain sensitive information, and (2) this is the only submodule in the repository.  (Git will stop fetching submodules when one fails, so this could prevent other submodules from being properly fetched.)